# Не могу вывести данные из UserDefault в tableview

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4

Всем доброго времени суток.
Хочу сделать так чтобы записи добавлялись на страницу "Избранное"
В первом контроллере сделал action на кнопку:

```
 let ud = UserDefaults.standard
 let news_title = ["Первая новость", "Вторая новость", "Третья новость", "Четвертая новость", "Пятая новость"]  

@IBAction func star_button(_ sender: UIButton) {

if sender.currentImage == UIImage(named: "star_active") {
    sender.setImage(UIImage(named:"star_inactive.png"), for: .normal)
    ud.removeObject(forKey:"savemain")
}
else {
    sender.setImage( UIImage(named:"star_active.png"), for: .normal)

    ud.set(news_title, forKey:"savemain")
    ud.synchronize()
}
    print(UserDefaults.standard.dictionaryRepresentation().keys)
```

}

Во втором контроллере сделал вывод в tableview

```
var array : [String] = []  
func initial(){
    var data : [String]?

    data = UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "savemain")

    if let it = data {
        self.array = it
    }
}  

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return array.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell2", for: indexPath) as! MainTableViewCell
    cell.textlabel.text = array[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

Через print вижу что массив сохраняется в UserDefault. Не могу вывести. Спасибо заранее

Comment: news_title это что за объект? 
Как создается объект ud?

P.S так как когда тут кот наплакал, предполагаю, что numberOfRowsInSection вызывается до initial()
Попробуйте сразу после self.array = it вызвать tableView.reloadData()

Comment: Да, простите за это, я обновил код в теме.
Я вставил после self.array  = it
Выходит ошибка unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value

Comment: Пришлите пожалуйста код, где вызывается функция initial()
А так же, после self.array = it напишите следующее: 
print(tableView == nil ?? "TableView is Nil" : "TableView is Not Nil")